# Boolean logic calculation for dependent variables

Tags: logic, boolean

Given the following problem:

Which statements are equivalent:

```
if x == y and y == z or z == x:
    do something
if x == y and (y == z or z == x):
   do something
if (x == y and y == z) or z == x:
   do Something
```

How do you create an exhaustive list of test cases to check all possibilities?

Here is my approach: We have three relationships:

x==y
x==z
y==z

each relationship can either be true or false.  I understand that there are 2^3 possibilities but since these conditions are not independent how many valid logical relationships do I have?  Is there a formula?

I count 5

```
x    y    z          x=y    x=z    y=z
1    1    1          true   true   true
1    1    2          true   false  false
1    2    1          false  true   false
1    2    2          false  false  true
1    2    3          false  false  false
```

essentially, any truth table row where there are only 2 true's is logically inconsistent.

```
x=y  & x=z  -> y=z
x=y  & x!=z -> y!=z
x!=y & x=z  -> y!=z
```

for a small problem like this, it's easy to find the solution by inspection.  Suppose though we have 20 variables, seems like we should be able to calculate the number of valid rows in the truth table.

Comment: please help me understand why this question is being down voted.  I'm trying really hard to ask a good question.  The answer is obvious for independent variables but not so for dependent ones

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but it doesn't depend on the "structure" of the relationship. If you have $n$ variables, the exhaustive method would take you to evaluate $2^n$ possibilities. That's because each variable can be either $0$ or $1$ (boolean algebra). So every time you see e.g. $3$ variables, then you should check $2^3=8$ rows. Does that make any sense?

Comment: as stated in the problem the structure of the relationship is x==y, x==z, y==z where each relationship can be true or false.  It's easy in this problem with 3 variables to figure out which of the 2^n relationships are logically possible.  But suppose you have 20 or 30 relationships how can you quickly determine which one are impossible to build a use case?